# Linq to EF - populate a (fairly simple) hierarchical object from EDM C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, parent-child, hierarchy

I want to populate a parent object and a list of its children (first level children) using linq to EF. The (eventual) method would take the parent input and return the item and all its children. The example I posted is using parented==null to get top-level item. Just trying to get it to work first.

I am posting the create table statement, with sample data at the end of this post.

The object I'm trying to populate is called AttributeObject. It contains a Name (which is the "Value" column in the database) as well as a list of its children.

```
    public class AttributeObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<AttributeObject> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm struggling with loading the children. The code I have is:

```
        var attributes =
            (from attr in model.CategoryAttributes.Include(c => c.Children)
             where attr.ParentID == null
             select new AttributeObject()
             {
                 Name = attr.Value,
                 ID = attr.ID,
                 Children = attr.Children.AsEnumerable().ToList<AttributeObject>()
             });
```

The error I'm getting is that it cannot convert from CategoryAttribute (Entity Type) to AttributeObject

Thanks very much

SQL Table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [CategoryAttribute](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Value] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL,
        [ParentID] [int] NULL,
        [Weight] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_ECM_CategoryAttributeValues] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ON 

    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (1, N'Document Properties', NULL, 1)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (2, N'Document Group', 1, 1)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (3, N'Document Type', 2, 1)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (12, N'IS Agreement', 2, 5)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (13, N'IS Guides', 2, 5)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (70, N'Service Agreement', 12, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (71, N'Software Licensing', 12, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (72, N'SOW', 12, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (73, N'Support Contracts', 12, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (74, N'Administration Guide', 13, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (75, N'Developer Guide', 13, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (76, N'Installation Guide', 13, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (77, N'Procedure', 13, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (78, N'Release Notes', 13, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (79, N'Training Manual', 13, 8)
    INSERT [CategoryAttribute] ([ID], [Value], [ParentID], [Weight]) VALUES (80, N'User Guide', 13, 8)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CategoryAttribute] OFF
    ALTER TABLE [CategoryAttribute]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ECM_CategoryAttributeValues_ECM_CategoryAttributeValues] FOREIGN KEY([ParentID])
    REFERENCES [CategoryAttribute] ([ID])
    ALTER TABLE [CategoryAttribute] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ECM_CategoryAttributeValues_ECM_CategoryAttributeValues]
```

Comment: Why are you using class AttributeObject and not the EF Model class CategoryAttribute?

Comment: Because this is in a WCF service, I don't want to expose my EF model to the client. Good question - sorry I didn't mention hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
             var attributes =
                                (from attr in model.CategoryAttributes.Include(c => c.Children)
                                 where attr.ParentID == null
//Edited Here
                                 select new
            {
                Name = attr.Value,
                ID = attr.ID,
                Children = attr.Children
                .Select(c => new AttributeObject() { Name = c.Value, ID = c.ID })
                        .ToList()
            })
   //and Here execute the query with LINQ to Entities
    .AsEnumerable()
   //correctly cast to AttributeObject with LINQ to Object
                .Select(n => 
                    new AttributeObject() {
                Name=n.Name,
                ID=n.ID,
                Children=n.Children

            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I get the following error: "The type 'AttributeObject' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order."

Comment: sorry for this,
i'll build a sample project to check this

Comment: @JFL I found a working solution but couldn't help about the non elegant looks
note: Original answer edited